# I require a VB script to suppress the "UNKNOWN APPLICATION" warning box

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, vbscript

I need help in suppressing this dialogue box on running third party application or using CD-ROM

[image]

Comment: What happens if you untick 'Always ask before opening this file'?

Comment: I can untick but next time I run it pops up again. I'm not that dumb.

Comment: IIRC this warning dialog only appears when the file is marked as downloaded (implemented as a NTFS Alternate Data Stream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will suppress the warning (it will click "Run").

```
@ECHO OFF

REM External app to launch
CALL E:\file_from_external_location.exe

REM Make a VBS-script that will switch to the warning and press "Run"
ECHO ^

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate "Open File - Security Warning"^

WScript.Sleep 500^

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "%%R"^

>vbs.vbs
CALL vbs.vbs
DEL vbs.vbs
```

Not sure if any of this is needed. If I call the app from the script there doesn't seem to be any warning about opening the program.

```
REM External app to launch
CALL E:\file_from_external_location.exe
```

Comment: Can we specify %username% in these fields?

Comment: @JoeJ. not sure exactly what you mean, but probably yes.